# tvOS keyboard language

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, tvos, uisearchcontroller

Is it possible to change onscreen keyboard language in tvOS?
I certainly didn't find a way of adding new keyboards in Apple TV Settings, but maybe there is a parameter you can specify on `UISearchController.searchBar` to switch to a different input language?

My Simulator as well as Apple TV are in English, but I'd like my app to be able to support other languages for input (e.g Russian). After all it's just a virtual on-screen keyboard.

Comment: if the answer I provided helped you to solve your problem, do you mind accepting it as an answer? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your apple TV go to Settings -> General -> Language, switch to the language you need (Russian). It will ask you if you're OK with Siri not being supported, hit OK, and voila :

[image]

this doesn't work in simulator unfortunately.

Also, you might try to create a custom keyboard, and make it's primaryLanguage whatever you need:
https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInputViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014279-CH1-DontLinkElementID_8

Comment: Sorry, Жень, I was absent this weekend. So there is no way you can add new keyboard (like you do in iOS) without changing the language of the whole system. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It seems impossible to create a custom keyboard by setting `inputView` in tvOS. Exceptions will be thrown if you try it. Someone prove me wrong, because being able to do this would be amazing. (My use case: Bluetooth keyboard instead of on-screen keyboard.)